# Error: TypeError: object.__init__() takes exactly one argument (the instance to initialize)

Tags: python, python-3.x, clase, python-3.7, herencia

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

class Vector(object):
    """docstring for Vector"""
    def __init__(self, length, elem=None):
        super(Vector, self).__init__()


class Vector2D(Vector):
    """docstring for Vector"""
    def __init__(self, rows, cols, elem=None):
        super(Vector, self).__init__(rows)

v = Vector2D(6, 3)
```

Estoy intentado programa un motor de **3D Rendering**, en modulo llamado **math**(.py) cree las clases **Vector** & **Vector2D**, en el código esperaría que hiciera al menos un vector unidimensional al pasarle a la clase padre el numero de filas (rows), pero por el contrario obtengo un error que según pude observar al no pasar rows a la clase padre no sucede.

Estuve Googleando un poco y encontré los mismos errores solo que por causas distintas, en todos los que vi el error se producía por que se llamaba a la función **super()** sin heredar previamente de la  clase padre, sin embargo en mi caso la sub-clase **Vector2D** hereda de la clase **Vector**.

¡Gracias por su tiempo espero que me puedan ayudar!

Comment: ¿No será que en `Vector2D` debieras hacer `super(Vector2D, self).__init__(rows)`?

Comment: Parece como que al crear, has cogido código de un sitio y de otro sin saber muy bien que hacer, ya que tienes cosas de Python 2 y Python 3. Entiendo por las etiquetas que estás en Python 3, si no es así, hazmelo saber por favor y te amplio la respuesta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El principal problema es entender `super()`.

## ¿Para qué sirve Super()?

La principal ventaja que nos trae `super()` es que nos permite referenciar a nuestra clase padre, con menor esfuerzo (lo cual no quita que se pueda referenciar sin super).

Esto es especialmente util cuando estás creando **multiples niveles de herencia**, es decir hijos, nietos, bisnietos, etc... No solo porque la sintaxis es más corta, si no porque cuando ves `super()` **ya sabes directamente que es la clase padre**, sin tener que buscar por el código, qué demonios es `vector`.

Quedo tu ejemplo comentado:

```
#clase padre
class Vector:
    """docstring for Vector"""
    def __init__(self, length, elem=None):
        self.length = length
        self.elem = elem #Inicializamos el atributo elemn

#clase hija
class Vector2D(Vector):
    """docstring for Vector"""
    def __init__(self, length, cols, elem=None):
        super().__init__(length, elem) #pasamos estos atributos a la clase padre
        self.cols = cols #Este atributo pertenece al hijo

#Tenemos todos los atributos.
v = Vector2D(6, 3)
print(v.length)
print(v.cols)
print(v.elem)
```

**Salida:**

```
6
3
None
```

## Explicación

1. Creamos la clase padre, sin nada adicional (al contrario que se hacía en Python 2)
2. En la clase hija le pasamos a la hora de definir, la clase padre `class Vector2d(Vector):`
3. Cuando definimos el constructor, primero pasamos los argumentos de la clase padre con `super().__init__(leght, elem)` y después los de la clase hija `self.cols = cols`.

Answer (score 0):

Espero te sirva este código modificado

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

class Vector(object):
    """docstring for Vector"""

    def __init__(self, rows,cols, elem=None):
        super(Vector, self).__init__()
        print("rows: "+str(rows))
        print("cols: "+str(cols))


class Vector2D(Vector):
    """docstring for Vector"""
    def __init__(self, rows, cols, elem=None):
        Vector.__init__(self,rows,cols)

v = Vector2D(1,2)
```

Saludos

Comment: Para pedir una aclaración si es posible, quisiera saber por qué sucede esto si al menos todo lo que sé debería estar bien el código original, sin embargo muchas gracias @Diego Valladares. Me ha funcionado perfectamente el código editado.